# Complete Elmah Logging Setup for asp.net web api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, elmah

I have been reading so many different posts the last hour. I cannot simply find one, start to finish article / tutorial on how to wire up elmah to do the following in asp.net web api 2:

1. Which nuget package to install
2. Log ALL exceptions, 500, 404 , 200 etc in controller and pipeline space
3. Store Exception In SQL or Memory
4. View the exceptions at `/elmah.axd`
5. Email Exceptions to email address.

I seem to have found bits and pieces of this all over the net, but not one that ties them all together. And if I must be honest I have not come right with it either.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Nuget package you need to install:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Elmah.Contrib.WebApi/

Check out the [project site](https://github.com/rdingwall/elmah-contrib-webapi) on github for this library. This library simply provides an ASP.NET Web API exception filter for Elmah. Elmah setup is pretty much standard. For setting up DB logging etc go the [Elmah project site](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) and read out the documentation.

Comment: You might be my new best friend with this. I couldn't get Elmah to log for anything until I came across this post, installed the above and now it's perfect. Thank you!